# magento : how to get additional details in soap api response

Tags: magento, soap, attributes, categories

Hi i am working on magento soap_v2_wsdl. now i want some additional data for example i want category image in the category tree.

i know there is no default method to get the detail. But i can over write the core file to get the result. Now i want to know which file do i have to change to get the category image in the category tree soap response. Thanks in advance.

i already try to edit *`Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api`* which is located in *`/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Api.php`* but it is not changing anything in the result.

Comment: As you're using v2 of the SOAP API, you'll need to update `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/wsdl.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Rule number one in Magento ***Absolutely never touch the `core` files*** the keyword in your mindset should be **`extend`** instead of `overwrite`.

In your case to see the result changed.

1. You need to clean the magento cache `rm -rf var/cache/*`
2. You need to clean the `wsdl` cache `rm -rf /tmp/wsdl-*`

Comment: Thanks for the help brother. but actually i already create a separate module for it.And it is working fine now :)